# What does Blackwell and Dubins (1962) actually prove?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to figure out what [Blackwell and Dubins'](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237864) famous "merging of opinions" result really says. On the face of it, it says that if two probability functions are mutually absolutely continuous (agree on which events have measure zero) then, as you conditionalise on more and more evidence, they get closer together (almost certainly). That is, the sequences of conditional probabilities $p^n$ and $q^n$ get closer (in total variation distance) as $n$ increases. But playing through some toy examples in my head, I'm confused by what it says...

So if we've got an infinite sequence of coin tosses $H_i$, and we consider $p(H_i =1) = \frac13$ for all $i$ and $q(H_i=1) = \frac23$ for all $i$, then the theorem should apply, right? That is, even though $p^n = p(-|H_1=h_1,H_2=h_2\dots H_n=h_n) = p$ (and likewise for $q$),
their main theorem should still apply, as far as I can tell.

But it seems to follow from the main theorem that for $\varepsilon < \frac13$, there is some $n$ such that for $m>n$ we have $d(p^m,q^m) < \varepsilon$ (where $d$ here is total variation distance). But since $p^m(H_{m+1}) = \frac13$ and $q^m(H_{m+1}) = \frac23$, that can't be right?

So my question is, **what have I got wrong?**

(Section 6 of their paper might be making this point, but I'm not sure I understand the upshot of their example is supposed to be.)

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading about this some more, and here's what I think is going wrong in the example I described.

$p$ and $q$ are not mutually absolutely continuous. $p$ gives probability 1 to the set of infinite sequences of outcomes with about $\frac13$ heads, while $q$ gives that set probability zero.